# Angular Formbuilder testing with Async Validator

Tags: angular

I have a an async validator for one of the fields in my form.

```
this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  ....
  partnerCode: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(6)], this.partnerCodeAvailabilityValidator.bind(this)],
})
```

This is the code for the validator:

```
partnerCodeAvailabilityValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
 return this.partnerService.getPartner(this.partner.userId, control.value).map(res => {
  if (Util.isNotNull(res) && Util.isNotNull(res.code) && this.partner.userId !== res.userId) {
    return { partnerCodeTaken: true }
  } else {
    return null
  }
 })
}
```

During tests even when I send an available partner code the form still shows an error for partnerCode entry

If I remove the async form validator, the test passes successfully

How can I ensure that the tests wait for the verdict from the async form validator before giving it's response?

Comment: Hi @suku, did you fix this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @JordiRuiz, I think I did manage to do it. I'll add the answer by tomorrow

Comment: I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @JordiRuiz, I have answered the question below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async validators don't return value. Hence you need to mock the response from an async validator. So first we clear async validator from any formcontrol and then add a mock async validator

inside the tests add:

```
component.registrationForm.controls['partnerCode'].clearAsyncValidators()
component.registrationForm.controls['partnerCode'].setAsyncValidators(mockPartnerCodeAvailabilityValidator.bind(this))
```

The mockPartnerCodeAvailabilityValidator code is:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms'

export async function mockPartnerCodeAvailabilityValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let nonAvailablePartnerCodes = ['SVEINS']
  if (nonAvailablePartnerCodes.includes(control.value)) {
    resolve({ partnerCodeTaken: true })
  } else {
    resolve(null)
  }
})
}
```